# Вызов статического метода из свойства текущего класса

Tags: php, ооп, yii, классы, объекты

В

```
$this->model
```

Хранится название Класса

Я попытался сделать так:

```
'targetClass' => $this->model::className()
```

Но редактор сразу мне подсказал, что я не прав.

Сделал сейчас так:

```
'targetClass' => function() {
    $className = $this->model;
    return $className::className();
}
```

Правильно ли я делаю? Какие есть ещё варианты? Желательно более короткие.

*info:* PHP7, Yii2

Comment: `$this->model::className()` судя по этой строке там храниться объект. И зачем вам className что он возвращает? p.s. попробуйте так `{$this->model}::className();`

Comment: на `php7` можно так : `($this->model)::className();` на php5 эта же конструкция выдаст `Parse error`

Comment: @Naumov Попробовал, но PhpStorm 2016.1.2 ругается. Пробовал сам сначала так сделать, кстати. Странно, но почему не хочет?

Comment: Ну я только, что это сделал на php7 , все работает на 5 выдает ошибку.

Comment: @redroid У меня всё же ругается. Не могу пока понять почему. Я переделал вот так:     'targetClass' => "api\\modules\\v1\\models\\$this->model"

Comment: так `var_dump($this->model)` в студию.

Comment: string(5) "Photo"

Comment: `редактор сразу мне подсказал, что я не прав.`........ `но PhpStorm 2016.1.2 ругается` - а более конкретно можно? в чем не прав? на что ругается? что вы его не кормите или что на себя одеяло перетягиваете когда спите?

Comment: и лучше вообще описать более полно что вы делаете.... а то вот это `'targetClass' => function() {
    $className = $this->model;
    return $className::className();
}` без контекста выглядит странно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно писать $this->model->className - PHP позволяет, а можно заюзать get_class($this->model)